# OsGeo4W (QGIS 2.18.9): GRASS i.maxlik can't find signature on Windows 10 network

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w, grass-7.0, windows-10

On a Windows 10 network running in the PC pool of our institution, `i.maxlike` from GRASS 7 produces the following error message when using a signature file produced by `i.cluster`. Using it from QGIS 2.18.9

Important: I use the same dataset and configuration on my Ubuntu system and it works like a charm.

Here's the log of the algorithm:

```
Algorithmus i.maxlik - Classifies the cell spectral reflectances in imagery data. startet...
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs"
r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_08_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643413 --overwrite -o
r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_07_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643414 --overwrite -o
r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_06_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643415 --overwrite -o
r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_05_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643416 --overwrite -o
r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_04_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643417 --overwrite -o
r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_03_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643418 --overwrite -o
r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_02_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643419 --overwrite -o
r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_01_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643420 --overwrite -o
g.region n=5503098.66018 s=5448566.77389 e=3543897.33774 w=3457687.73765 res=15.0060226441
i.group group=tmp14976028643421 subgroup=tmp14976028643422 input=tmp14976028643413,tmp14976028643414,tmp14976028643415,tmp14976028643416,tmp14976028643417,tmp14976028643418,tmp14976028643419,tmp14976028643420
MD C:\Users\ty4417\AppData\Local\Temp\processing33048a9a4ed64b029a8f482a6575b628\grassdata\temp_location\PERMANENT\group\tmp14976028643421\subgroup\tmp14976028643422\sig
COPY /Y E:/RESULTS/sign063.txt C:\Users\ty4417\AppData\Local\Temp\processing33048a9a4ed64b029a8f482a6575b628\grassdata\temp_location\PERMANENT\group\tmp14976028643421\subgroup\tmp14976028643422\sig\sign063.txt
i.maxlik signaturefile="sign063.txt" group="tmp14976028643421" subgroup="tmp14976028643422" output=output5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 reject=reject5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 --overwrite
g.region raster=output5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805
r.out.gdal --overwrite -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=output5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 output="E:/RESULTS/class063.tif"
g.region raster=reject5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805
r.out.gdal --overwrite -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=reject5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 output="C:\Users\ty4417\AppData\Local\Temp\processing33048a9a4ed64b029a8f482a6575b628\f7ae4eded1954935b8adb3789a8cba12\reject.tif"

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set HOME=C:\Users\ty4417 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GISRC=C:\Users\ty4417\.qgis2\\processing\processing.gisrc7 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set WINGISBASE=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GISBASE=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GRASS_PROJSHARE=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\share\proj 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GRASS_MESSAGE_FORMAT=plain 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>if "" == "" set PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\qgis\bin;{app};C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>if not "" == "" set PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\qgis\bin;{app};C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GRASS_VERSION=7.2.1 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>if not "" == "" goto langset 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\etc\winlocale"`) DO @set LANG=%i 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PY 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set PYTHONPATH=;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\etc\python;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\etc\wxpython\n 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="MAPSET=PERMANENT" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="LOCATION=temp_location" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="LOCATION_NAME=temp_location" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="GISDBASE=C:\Users\ty4417\AppData\Local\Temp\processing33048a9a4ed64b029a8f482a6575b628\grassdata" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="GRASS_GUI=text" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs" 
Die Standard Region wurde auf die neue Projektion aktualisiert. Wenn Sie aber mehrere Mapsets haben, sollten Sie `g.region -d` in jedem ausführen, um die Einstellungen von der Standardregion zu übernehmen. 
Projektionsinformationen aktualisiert 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_08_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643413 --overwrite -o 
WARNUNG: Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external komplett. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_07_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643414 --overwrite -o 
WARNUNG: Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external komplett. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_06_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643415 --overwrite -o 
WARNUNG: Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external komplett. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_05_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643416 --overwrite -o 
WARNUNG: Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external komplett. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_04_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643417 --overwrite -o 
WARNUNG: Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external komplett. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_03_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643418 --overwrite -o 
WARNUNG: Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external komplett. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_02_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643419 --overwrite -o 
WARNUNG: Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external komplett. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="E:\L8_2014_06_08_BAND_01_REPR_CLIP_TOAR.tif" band=1 output=tmp14976028643420 --overwrite -o 
WARNUNG: Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external komplett. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.region n=5503098.66018 s=5448566.77389 e=3543897.33774 w=3457687.73765 res=15.0060226441 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>i.group group=tmp14976028643421 subgroup=tmp14976028643422 input=tmp14976028643413,tmp14976028643414,tmp14976028643415,tmp14976028643416,tmp14976028643417,tmp14976028643418,tmp14976028643419,tmp14976028643420 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Gruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Gruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Gruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Gruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Gruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Gruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Gruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Gruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Untergruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Untergruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Untergruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Untergruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Untergruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Untergruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Untergruppe hinzu. 
Füge Rasterkarte zu der Untergruppe hinzu. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>MD C:\Users\ty4417\AppData\Local\Temp\processing33048a9a4ed64b029a8f482a6575b628\grassdata\temp_location\PERMANENT\group\tmp14976028643421\subgroup\tmp14976028643422\sig 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>COPY /Y E:/RESULTS/sign063.txt C:\Users\ty4417\AppData\Local\Temp\processing33048a9a4ed64b029a8f482a6575b628\grassdata\temp_location\PERMANENT\group\tmp14976028643421\subgroup\tmp14976028643422\sig\sign063.txt 
Syntaxfehler. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>i.maxlik signaturefile="sign063.txt" group="tmp14976028643421" subgroup="tmp14976028643422" output=output5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 reject=reject5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 --overwrite 
FEHLER: Kann die Signaturdatei nicht öffnen. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.region raster=output5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 
FEHLER: Rasterkarte konnte nicht gefunden werden. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.out.gdal --overwrite -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=output5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 output="E:/RESULTS/class063.tif" 
FEHLER: Rasterkarte oder Gruppe nicht gefunden. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.region raster=reject5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 
FEHLER: Rasterkarte konnte nicht gefunden werden. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.out.gdal --overwrite -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=reject5ea6c74ba00143a88f0308a1f2058805 output="C:\Users\ty4417\AppData\Local\Temp\processing33048a9a4ed64b029a8f482a6575b628\f7ae4eded1954935b8adb3789a8cba12\reject.tif" 
FEHLER: Rasterkarte oder Gruppe nicht gefunden. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>exit 
Converting outputs
Lade Ergebnis Layer

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Classification
Reject Threshold
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm
```

Comment: I'm using QGIS 2.18.16 on a Windows 8.1 and getting the same error. We spotted that the COPY command after the MD is changing the \ to a / for the input signature file. If this line is run in the command line window with the / put back to \ then the COPY command executes. I believe this is the Source of the problem. We intend to raise a bug fix.

Answer (score 1):

I have just filed a [bug report with patch](http://issues.qgis.org/issues/18185) that fixes this issue.

The python code wrapping the call to the GRASS algorithm is switching the path separator characters and causing a copy command to fail on Windows OSes.